# Simple Injector in Asp.net core error, the instance is requested outside the context of a ASP.NET Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, simple-injector

I got the following error

> The IMapperFactory is registered as 'ASP.NET Request' lifestyle, but the instance is requested outside the context of a ASP.NET Request.

in Simple Injector with ASP.NET Core, below is the line where the exception thrown out,

```
var controller =
    container.GetInstance(context.ActionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo.AsType());
```

It's set as `AspNetRequestLifestyle`,

```
appBuilder.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
    using (containerMap[key].BeginExecutionContextScope())
    {
        await next();
    }
});

container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AspNetRequestLifestyle();
```

Where is the error out from?

Comment: Please show the complete stack trace.

Comment: And what is `containerMap[key]`? Do you have multiple containers? Is is possible you are resolving from a different containre than where you started the scope for?

Comment: I really would like to help you, but with the amount of information you currently gave, it's impossible to reproduce. Please post the minimal working code to allow anyone to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Steven, it was WcfOperationLifeStyle, and now in the migration, i changed to AspNetRequestLifeStyle. each url has its own container. the key is unique for each url.

Comment: WAT? Why does each url have a different container?

Comment: @Steven, as it's an adapter service, which needs to dynamically load assemblies based on the version, (and some other info) in the url, like /v1/clienta/service.svc, /v1/clientb/service.svc

Comment: Creating container instances has a lot of overhead, and it's typically not adviced to have more than once container. It also makes it hard to share instances across app-domain. (this holds for every DI container btw).

Comment: Yes, we know that. The initialization is quite slow, but once it's done, it's really fast. We're working on migrating wcf to asp.net core mvc, in wcf, it just works fine,

Comment: I still wonder why AspNetRequestLifestyle doesn't replace well WcfOperationLifestyle, do they behavior differently? now, what shall the lifestyle be instead? @Steven

Comment: So... how exactly did you expect the `WcfOperationLifestyle` to work in ASP.NET Core? There is no WCF in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @Steven yeah... in wcf, we use fileless activation, and we set baseAddress in web.config/serviceHostingEnvironment section, and use SimpleInjectorServiceHostFactory.SetContainer(container), and WcfOperationLifestyle; which means one baseAddress has its own container. But in asp.net core mvc, there's no such a thing, so we have to use dictionary to keep them, key is composed of url, value is the container itself. And now I have the obstacle.. or, is there any better recommended way to replace wcf?

Comment: `SimpleInjectorServiceHostFactory.SetContainer(container)` stores the container in a static variable, global to the app-domain, so I find it *very unlikely* that you are actually using multiple container instances (you might create them, but you are only using one of them). So since you are using only one container, you should this same method in ASP.NET Core as well.

Comment: Since you are moving away from SOAP, it would be good to take a step back and take a look for more things to optimize here. For instance, when using [commands](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) and [queries](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91), you can reduce your WCF or Web API layer to a few lines of infrastructure. [Here's an example for WCF](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=95) and [here is one](https://github.com/dotnetjunkie/solidservices/tree/master/src/WebApiService) for Web API. Same aplies to .NET Core.

Comment: @Steven, :) much appreciate, let me deep look inside (hope I can understand , oops..)